# Implementing angular-ui-router with java servlet webapp context path

Tags: angularjs, servlets, web-applications, angular-ui-router

Basically the problem is related to the path ui-router redirects when page is reloaded.

I have a java application with context kiosk-ui so the url is: `http://localhost:8080/kiosk-ui`.

The client side is implemented using angularjs and for the url management I use angular-ui-router. The application is a single page app so I have states.

This is the ui-router configuration.

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $stateProvider

            .state("rewards", {
                url: "/",
                controller: 'RewardsCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'templates/reward-selection.tpl.html'
            })            

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
    })
```

On initial load of the page, I'm being redirected to `http://localhost:8080/kiosk-ui/#/` but when I refresh the page, router redirects me to `http://localhost:8080/#/`. So somehow it skips the webapp context path.

I tried to configure the router in a different way, so I will post that scenario as well.

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

            $stateProvider

                .state("rewards", {
                    url: "/kiosk-ui",
                    controller: 'RewardsCtrl',
                    templateUrl: 'templates/reward-selection.tpl.html'
                })            

            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/kiosk-ui/");
        })
```

On the initial load of the page I'm redirected to `http://localhost:8080/kiosk-ui/#/kiosk-ui`.
When I refresh the page it still redirects me to the same url but it's not what I want.

I want to have `http://localhost:8080/kiosk-ui/#/` and when refreshed to stay there...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

use the `<base>` element. you can use your server side template engine to write the correct `href`

http://www.verdantrefuge.com/writing/2013/angularjs-changing-app-path-base-element/